# How to check null values of text fields and put it in if else statements to redirect it to error page?

Tags: java, null, if-statement

In following code there is a problem in If Else statement. Only Else part of Request dispatcher is executing even if I don't enter anything in Text Fields. Also, how to check null values of text fields inside Java?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                                           throws ServletException, IOException {

String Email    = request.getParameter("email");
String Password = request.getParameter("password");

    if (Email == null || Password == null){             

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("JSP Address");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    } else {

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("JSP Address");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use the method [StringUtils.isBlank(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) in the commons-lang ([http://commons.apache.org/lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)) for this type of checking. It checks if the string is null, empty, or if it contains only whitespaces.

Comment: I will try using it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the parameters become **null** only if the **form** does not send them at all.

Suppose your form is like this:

```
input type=text name="pass" (not password)
```

then the parameter you are using in `request.getParameter` is not present so it is **null**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the values are (non-null) empty strings? Try:

```
   if (Email == null || Password == null || Email.equals("") || Password.equals("")){
```

Comment: Yes! this might be the solution to my problem. But as suggested using Apache Commons has made my life easier. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the fields are coming in as empty strings rather than nulls, but we can't tell that for sure without seeing more code.

Running it in a debugger or adding debug prints would clarify.